# iconv: illegal input sequence at position

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8, text-processing, iconv

I have a bash script which downloads some files from a url and stores them into a folder named "data1". Since these files are downloaded as .zip then the next step is to unzip them. After that, the variables `extension` and `encoding` are get from every file, where `extension` is the type of file (txt, csv, docx) and `encoding` is the encoding format of each file (ISO, utf-8). Since the files that this script downloads are not in utf-8 format i have to perform this transformation. This is the line which performs the encoding:

```
iconv -f $encoding -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT $name2.$extension -o conversion_$name2.$extension;
```

As you can see, I have to pass two parameters, the file to be encoded to utf-8 format and the name of the output file which will be: conversion_(name of the original file).(extension of the original file). However, I'm getting the following error:

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 1234704
```

This error is affecting the *datos_abiertos_covid19.zip* file which after the unzipping process is named as *200715COVID19MEXICO.csv* (but it changes depending on the day this script is run). Does anyone knows how I can avoid this error? I specifically need all of the files downloaded to be in utf-8 format. I would really appreciate your help.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
! /usr/bin/bash

# creating folders

mkdir data1

cd data1

# downloading data

wget http://187.191.75.115/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/datos_abiertos_covid19.zip
wget http://187.191.75.115/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/diccionario_datos_covid19.zip


# unziping data
for i in `ls | grep .zip`; do unzip $i; done


# this for will iterate over all the files contained on the data1 folder
for name in `ls -F -1 | grep -v / | grep -v zip`; do 

        # getting extension of current file
        extension=`echo $name | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`;

        # getting encoding format of current file
        encoding=`file -i $name | sed 's/=/ /g' |awk '{print $4}'`;

        # echo $encoding

        query="s/\.$extension//g"
        # echo $query
        name2=`echo $name | sed -e $query`;
        # echo $name2
        # echo $name" "$extension" "$encoding" "$name2
   
        # encoding current file
        iconv -f $encoding -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT $name2.$extension -o conversion_$name2.$extension;

done

mkdir old

mv `ls | grep -v "conversion_" | grep -v "old"` old
```

Since this script is intended to be run automatically every 24 hours, then I need the old data (data from a day before) to be stored in another place. That's why at the end of the script a new folder is created and all the "old files" are moved to the folder named "old".

Comment: The error message you get means that the file being converted is in fact not in the encoding you specified.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin but how it could not be if I'm actually getting it directly from each file on the for.

Comment: The file may have mixed encoding. For instance, partially utf8 and partially iso88591. Very difficult to deal with.

Comment: I figured it out. I've been working for days with these files and since the very first day the encoding format was iso88591, but yesterday it was changed to utf-8. The error I was having it was while converting from utf-8 to utf-8.